# Decentralized Identities (DIDs) with biometrics based instead of public key

Tags: erc725, erc735

is it possible to store and keep biometrics on evm and have this biometric validated through smart contracts? Say a erc 735 based contract?

Since ones public keys and private keys are not the easiest thing to remember.

What data type can one use to store biometric details?